# Concurrency safe pivoting of Azure Service Fabric Reliable Collections

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I have a service that has a bunch of incoming Orders that I store into an IReliableDictionary. As new orders come in, I need to update and maintain a separate sorted list of those orders throughout the lifetime of my program.

How do I efficiently and concurrency pivot the data in the IReliableDictionary into a different sorted collection such that I avoid deadlocks and don't have to rebuild the sorted list from scratch every time a new order comes in?

EDIT: After looking at the documentation I believe I can achieve this by updating my local memory sorted collection after an update before a commit.

```
        using (var tx = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction())
        {
            bool addOk = await orderDictionary.TryAddAsync(tx, 123, someOrderToAdd);
            if (addOk)
            {
                this.SortedOrders.Add(someOrderToAdd);
            }
            await tx.CommitAsync();
        }
```

**Can someone confirm that my understanding of the documentation is correct, and that something like the above implementation will not cause concurrency issues?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reliable collections notifications and store in sorted list. This will ensure that you never miss out on events related to dictionary.

Comment: What's the recommended usage of that? Is the notification in-order/concurrency safe? Or, should I lock on the sorted list and then insert (assuming the reliabledictionary doesn't maintain some sort of Update lock during the notification)?

Comment: If u use a concurrentdictionary, you don't need a lock. You do need  a lock for sorted list.  The events arrive in order. Don't do expensive operations in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for the lifetime of the process, and if it's no problem to have only `Orders` from within the partition, maybe you can use a regular concurrent collection. For [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx), a `ConcurrentQueue<Order>`.

You can also use an [event driven approach](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors), signalling a timestamped `OrderReceivedEvent` every time an `Order` is received. Then you can subscribe to those events in a separate service that stores them somewhere.

Or you can use a distributed cache like [Redis](https://redis.io/) (in a [Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-containers-overview)) to keep `Orders` temporarily.

Another option could be to use SQL server for `Order` data, instead of reliable collections.